# Triple nested loop complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I'm trying to determine the complexity of the following structure:

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)

for (j = 1; j < o; j++)

for (k = 1; k < p; k++)

```
print "Hello world!"
```

Normally, for a triple loop like this, I believe the complexity is O(n^3), but the undefined variables "o" and "p" are throwing a wrench in the works. I've done
some hunting around, and the best I can surmise is that it might be O(n * o * p), depending on what values are assigned to n, o and p. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

$O(nop)$ is indeed exactly the best upper bound one can conclude for this program without additional information. The bound $O(n^3)$ cannot be shown unless you know $o$ and $p$ are themselves $O(n)$. On the other hand, if you knew $o$ and $p$ were actually constants, then you could prove a bound of $O(n)$ for the entire program.

Comment: That's what I suspected, and good to know for future cases. Thanks!

Comment: @ZapRowsdower Glad this helps. If this answers your question, be sure to click the checkmark to mark this as the accepted answer. You can also upvote if you find the answer useful.